# DestroyAPIView Django rest validation

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

```
class DeleteLedgerCategory(DestroyAPIView):
    serializer_class = CategorySerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Category.objects.filter(company = self.request.user.currently_activated_company, id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return queryset

    def preform_destroy(self, instance):
        if instance.is_default == True:
            raise ValueError("Cannot delete default system category")
        return instance.delete()
```

In above class based view. I need to add custom validation error message. ie. if instance.is_default == True: raise error... and only allow to delete the instance if no error encounters. If any unclear question. Do comment

Comment: On a side note, you should define`get_object` instead of defining `get_queryset`.

Answer (score 11):

Instead of just raise error you can customize response in `destroy` method:

```
from rest_framework.response import Response

class DeleteLedgerCategory(DestroyAPIView):
    serializer_class = CategorySerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Category.objects.filter(company = self.request.user.currently_activated_company, id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return queryset

    def destroy(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = self.get_object()
        if instance.is_default == True:
            return Response("Cannot delete default system category", status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        self.perform_destroy(instance)
```

Comment: but why can't we customize validation in perform_destroy function.

Comment: @SumanAstani `perform_destroy` simply, well, perform deletion:) It's called by `destroy` method on the other side whiche generate HTTPResponse.

Comment: @SumanAstani I'm not sure if your suggested edits will work. In case of simple `self.perform_destroy(instance)` view will not return any response.

Comment: It works. the perform_destroy() method delete the instance. This is default class based function in DestroyModelMixin class

Comment: Don't forget to return a Response after `perform_destroy`, otherwise it returns None and crashes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the destroy method here but you have to return a response whether it is successful or not

```py
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status

class DeleteLedgerCategory(DestroyAPIView):
    serializer_class = CategorySerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Category.objects.filter(company = self.request.user.currently_activated_company, id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return queryset

    def destroy(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = self.get_object()
        if instance.is_default == True:
            return Response("Cannot delete default system category", status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)
        self.perform_destroy(instance)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```