# DestroyAPIView by several conditions

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have data models like:

```py
from django.db import models


class Student(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name


class Course(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField()
    start_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    end_date = models.DateField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class CourseParticipant(models.Model):
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, related_name='courses', on_delete=None)
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, related_name='students', on_delete=None)
    completed = models.BooleanField(null=True, default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.course
```

I have some serializer like:

```py
class AssignStudentToCourseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CourseParticipant
        fields = ('id', 'student', 'course')

class UnassignedStudentFromCourseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CourseParticipant
        fields = ('student_id', 'course_id')
```

I have views for it

```py
class AssignStudentToCourse(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = AssignStudentToCourseSerializer


class UnassignedStudentFromCourse(generics.DestroyAPIView):
    serializer_class = UnassignedStudentFromCourseSerializer
    queryset = CourseParticipant.objects.all()
```

I have a table `CourseParticipant` with some records

```
-------------------------------------------
| id         | course_id   | student_id   |
|------------|-------------|--------------|
| 1          |      2      |     2        |
| 2          |      3      |     2        |
| 3          |      2      |     3        |
| 4          |      2      |     4        |
-------------------------------------------
```

I need to delete records from this table by `course_id` and `student_id`. Now, use `DestroyAPIView` I can delete a `record` by `id`, but it's not done the right way. How I can delete `record` from my table by several condition?

Comment: similar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/50094223/7887883

Comment: If you want to delete records by `course_id` or `student_id`, then which parameter you would expect in url?

Comment: You should not use `DestroyAPIView` view, because it will create url like this `/resource/<pk>` to delete a specific resource of `pk`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with `DestroyAPIView` you can only delete the instance you are calling using the specific url

If you want to delete the `CourseParticipant` by calling student url

first create a view to get the student instance and get its related object and then delete it

```
class StudentApiView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Student.objects.all()


    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print(self.get_object(),)
        instance = self.get_object()
        course_participant_obj = CourseParticipant.objects.get(student=instance)
        course_participant_obj.delete()
        return Response('deleted', )
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar case in which I wanted to send a `DELETE` method to an API endpoint and have the backend determine individual objects to delete. You can use `DestroyAPIView` and override the `destroy` method to achieve this.

```py
class StudentApiView(generics.DestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Student.objects.all()

    def destroy(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Do logic here to get `course_participant` to delete, then
        course_participant.delete()

        # Don't return super().destroy(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```